# Can I use my wife's savings bank statement for UK Visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am applying for a standard tourist visa to the UK from India. It is a holiday trip with my wife and 2 kids.

I am the main financial provider and will be submitting my bank statements and payslips. I also wanted to submit my wife's savings account statement as there frequent transactions between our accounts and I wanted to provide it to clarify there is no funds parking and also as additional proof of funds towards our trip expenses, although it is not a lot.

My wife is also employed. My doubt is whether I should declare her employment in her application and submit her savings account statement for that application. Her salary and balance by itself would not be sufficient to cover any expenses.

My concern is if I don't declare her as employed, the officer will notice the salary credits in her account and may decide that I am not providing the correct information or willfully hiding facts.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you not 'declare her as employed'?

Your wife will be asked about her employment status on her application, and if you say she is unemployed when she is not that is lying on the application. Lying on an application form can possibly result in a ban from the country.

Submitting your wife's banking details can only help your situation, even if it is not by itself enough to cover your expenses. Presumably you do have enough between you to cover the cost of the trip and have enough left over for normal life.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed by myself I do have enough to cover the cost of the trip and have enough left over for normal life and I want to submit her bank details as it helps our case. But I am confused about what to state/submit on her application about her finances. I am the primary applicant and the rest of the family are dependents for visa and the trip. Since our applications will be tied together using the GFW numbers and the proofs will be submitted, is there no cause for concern on my part. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Vikky There’s no confusion. As DJClayworth says, state the truth about your wife’s financial circumstances. Just because she’s ‘dependent’ on you for some /all of the trip costs doesn’t change her own employment/financial situation.

Comment: @Traveller DJClayworth Thanks for your inputs. I mentioned my wife's employment and bank details on her application.The further question I have is what amount do I indicate for "amount in savings"? Mine and hers combined in my application and the same figure in hers with additional remarks explaining the same. Or do we keep the amounts separate in our respective applications?Should she mention any expenses from her savings towards the trip? New forms of March 29th 2019 do not allow us to enter 0 for expenses in dependants applications. Should I enter a token amount and clarify? Please help.

Comment: Hi Vicky. If you have another question please post it using the Ask Question button above.

Comment: @Vikky, do not falsify _anything_ in visa applications...